# What happens to an iTunes season pass for a TV show if the show is cancelled before the end of the season?

Tags: itunes

I know the basics of the Season Pass from the iTunes store for current TV shows - you can buy the pass in either HD or SD. Episodes that are currently available will download immediately, and future episodes will enter your download queue as they become available.

It looks like there is a slight discount for buying by the season, which I definitely like. I'd like to be able to do the season path math, but I do not know how to determine how many episodes for a season. A typical network season airs 23 episodes for a given show. So The Good Wife in HD, for example, costs 52.99 for Season 3. If 23 shows are delivered the cost is 2.30 per episode a discount of .69 per episode, or a savings of 15.78 on the season. But what if it is cancelled after only 10 episodes? Did I just pay 5.30 per episode? Will I get a refund?

I know this situation is unlikely on a show like The Good Wife, but it possible on this show and even likely on some new shows. Please do not answer with speculation, if you have personal experience with this issue, or can find an apple support document on this topic (my google search was not fruitful) I would appreciate it.

I have asked this question of Apple Support and I will post their answer if I do not get a definitive answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is stated in the [terms and conditions](http://www.apple.com/legal/itunes/us/terms.html) that you get a credit for the pro-rated shortfall should the studio fail to deliver the quantity of episodes you purchased.

Retail price means the price you paid divided equally by the episodes promised and not whatever a la carte pricing might also be available outside the bundled pass price.

Comment: Thanks. Now if I could just find where it says how many episodes are included in the season pass...

Comment: Even though iTunes doesn't state an anticipated count like the english wikipedia will about most shows well before they even start filming, I've never once heard anyone complain that Apple didn't credit them enough for any purchase problem after asking for a partial or full refund.